# I want to combine multiple REGEXREPLACE in google sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a google sheet and in 'column A' I have list of fruit names. I want to find and replace 5 types of fruits with code names

"Mango" to be replaced with "001"
"Apple" to be replaced with "002"
"Orange" to be replaced with "003"
"Banana" to be replaced with "004"
"Jackfruit" to be replaced with "005"

I have a formula to replace just one of the word. Below is the formula

=ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXREPLACE(Sheet1!A:A, "Mango", "001"))

How do I combine the formula to replace all fruits with code words?

Answer (score 1):

If it were me, I'd just use SWITCH:

```
=ArrayFormula(IFERROR(SWITCH(A:A,"mango","001","apple","002","orange","003","banana","004","jackfruit","005"),A:A))
```

Comment: Happy to help, Balaji. If you would, please take a moment to mark the answer as "Best Answer." It helps other contributors to know that this issue is now resolved, and it allows future seekers to quickly find answers to their own similar issues.